# Error: ORA-01848: day of year must be between 1 and 365 (366 for leap year) while extracting month and year from DateColumn(varchar(10))

Tags: oracle, date, datetime, oracle11g, sql-date-functions

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(Column_d, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'YYYY-MM') as Date_y FROM Table_d
```

Even want to get quarter from the same date which is again giving me the error ORA-01848 like

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(Column_d, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'mm')) IN ('01','02','03') THEN 'Q1'
WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(Column_d, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'mm')) IN ('04','05','06') THEN 'Q2'
WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(Column_d, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'mm')) IN ('07','08','09') THEN 'Q3'
ELSE 'Q4' END as QTR
FROM Table_d
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, nothing of what you posted returns ORA-01848. It is - usually, if not always - related to the `DDD` date format mask which represents day number within the year.

For example, this is correct, as day number `001` equals the 1st of January:

```
SQL> select to_date('001-2020', 'ddd-yyyy') from dual;

TO_DATE('0
----------
01.01.2020
```

This returns ORA-01848 as there's no day 405 in this (nor any) year:

```
SQL> select to_date('405-2020', 'ddd-yyyy') from dual;
select to_date('405-2020', 'ddd-yyyy') from dual
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01848: day of year must be between 1 and 365 (366 for leap year)
```

So: if you're doing anything like this, make sure that stored values are correct; I presume that not all of them are.

Besides, that's what happens when people store dates as strings into `VARCHAR2` (instead of `DATE` datatype) columns. I'm not saying that you're the *cause*, but you certainly are a *victim* here.

---

**[EDIT]**

Julian date, eh? In a comment, you said that you used such a query:

```
Select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(Julian_dateColumn+1900000, 'YYDDD'), 'YYDDD'), 'DD/MM/YYYY') as column_d from sometable
```

I doubt it as it is invalid (I suppose you have superfluous `, 'YYDDD')`).

Anyway, I have no idea why you tried to "convert" Julian date in such a manner. There's a simple and correct way to do so. Here's how:

This is today's date (21.05.2020) presented as Julian date:

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'j') julian from dual;

JULIAN
-------
2458991
```

That's kind of values you have stored in the table. In order to convert it to format you wanted (`yyddd`), you'd

```
SQL> select to_char(to_date(2458991, 'j'), 'yyddd') as column_d from dual;

COLUM
-----
20142
```

I suggest you use this instead of code you currently have, i.e.

```
SQL> create or replace view table_d as
  2    select to_char(to_date(julian_datecolumn, 'j'), 'yyddd') as column_d
  3    from sometable;

View created.

SQL> select * From table_d;

COLUM
-----
20142

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi, the column is derived from another table and is converted from a Julian date.

Comment: ` create view table_d as Select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(Julian_dateColumn+1900000, 'YYDDD'), 'YYDDD'), 'DD/MM/YYYY')  as column_d from sometable;  ` and then If I am using this table (column) to extract year and month then I am getting that error ORA-01848.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're doing it wrong. I edited my answer and posted some more info. Have a look, please.